# Promise not resolving to value when returned

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a recursive function that resolve a mapped array correctly recursively.

```
const postCommentsRecursive = (author, permlink) => {
  return client.database.call('get_content_replies', [author, permlink])
    .then(replies => Promise.all(replies.map(r => {
      if (r.children > 0) {
        return postCommentsRecursive(r.author, r.permlink)
          .then(children => {
            r.replies = children;
            return r;
          })
      }else {
        return r;
      }
    })))
}
```

But when I added another data fetch, the return from `then` stays a promise:

```
const postCommentsRecursive = (author, permlink) => {
  return client.database.call('get_content_replies', [author, permlink])
    .then(replies => Promise.all(replies.map(r => {
//NEW CODE START
      const votes = client.database
        .call('get_active_votes', [r.author, r.permlink])
        .then(av => {
          return av;
        });
      r['active_votes'] = votes;
//NEW CODE END
      if (r.children > 0) {
        return postCommentsRecursive(r.author, r.permlink)
          .then(children => {
            r.replies = children;
            return r;
          })
      }else {
        return r;
      }
    })))
}
```

`av` is the array value, great. But when I add it to the object from `votes`, it is a `Promise` instead.

Each `replies` child object is still resolved as a value, but inside each `r` when I add `votes` to `r` as `r['active_votes'] = votes`, the value set in the object is a `Promise {<resolved>: Array(1)}`.

[image]

I can't figure out how to get the actual `Array(1)` as a value, not the `Promise` as a value. How do I just get the `Array` as a value, and not the `Promise`?

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot escape from promises. Once you got inside a promise - everything else should be inside a promise as well. `.then` always returns a promise so you need to pass handlers to `.then` to deal with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're assigning `r.votes` to be a `Promise`. Instead, you need to go into the `.then` of that promise if you want to mutate `r`. (Conceptually, it's the same as what you're doing in the `r.children > 0` block)

```js
      return client.database
        .call('get_active_votes', [r.author, r.permlink])
        .then(av => {
          // mutate r
          r.active_votes = av;
          // now return it so that this entire promise resolves with `r`
          return r;
        });
```

`async/await` generally makes code like this a little clearer:

```js
r.active_votes = await client.database
        .call('get_active_votes', [r.author, r.permlink])
```

Comment: You can make the `then` part of this shorter and less readable: `.then(av => (r.active_votes = av, r))`

Comment: Where can I put the async part of the await? await can't be on it's own... thanks. I thought of async/await, but couldn't get it to apply in here.

Comment: Your first solution works, with some modification (no return on the `client.database` part. Thank you very much! :)